# Select elements text and add a comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get some elements in my page using the DOM: `$('ul li').text()`

And after that (or maybe during that) I would like to add a comma. In some cases the text that I'm getting has white spaces and other characters.

As a result I would love to get an array like this for example `["first text", "second element", "third"]`

What would be the easier way to do that using javascript functions or jQuery?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: An example might help to calrify what you want to do.

Comment: jquery makes life easier, but your question needs to be more accurate with better examples

Comment: check it : http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to put the text of each `li` in your selector into an array. If so, try this:

```
var liText = $('ul li').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log($.unique(liText));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HK4AT/1)

Comment: By the way, how can I remove the duplicated values now? Is there a way using that map option to get only unique values?

Comment: You can use `$.unique(array)` to remove dupes, I've updated my example for you.

Comment: Thanks Rory.
I can see your example working perfectly, but what I'm doing wrong in mine?
http://jsfiddle.net/zY2hY/
As you can see I'm getting some names repeated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because you need to sort them to group the duplicate values together, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/zY2hY/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method. Its goal is to return an array of mapped value. Get the text content of your elements in the callback and you'll end-up with an array of your element's text content.

The use the Array.join() method to return a comma-separated string of your array elements (in your case the elements' text).

```
var els = $('li');

var arr = $.map(els, function(item) {
    return $(item).text();
});

var texts = arr.join(',');​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8NY27/)**

Answer (score 1):

if you wish to have the array of words based on the presence of space you could use the `join` javascript method.
I'm not familiar with the jQuery map method which is another favourite.

```
var res_arr = new Array();
$("ul li").each(function(e) {
  res_arr[e] = $(this).text();
});
var output = res_arr.join(",");
```

so the output will contain the elements seperated by comma.

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors trying to use your code!
SyntaxError: syntax error
res_arr[] = $(this).text();

Comment: @reycoy oops... edited code [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8NY27/6/), should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new Array();
$('ul li').each(function(){
    result.push($(this).text());
})
return result;//get a array,if you want a string you can use result.join(',') or     //result.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a tiny plugin for this

```
$.fn.csv = function(){
    var csv = '';

    this.each(function(){
        csv += $(this).text() + ',';
    });

    return csv;
};
```

And use it as follows..

```
alert($('selector').csv());
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8NY27/5/).